# SQL computation - recursive reduction

Tags: mysql, sql-server, teradata

I am looking for a solution in SQL [I need to implement the logic within Teradata script].

I have 2 tables as shown below:

Table A

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2  
CB2       10  
CB1       20  
CB3       30
```

Table B

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2  
P1        10  
P2        15  
P3        15  
P4        10  
P5        10
```

Result needed - TABLE C

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   COLUMN3
CB2        P1        10
CB1        P2        15
CB1        P3         5
CB3        P3        10
CB3        P4        10
CB3        P5        10
```

Logic behind table 3 is as below:

1. Consume records from Table A and Table B based on values in column 2
   of both these tables to make up the records in Table C.
2. Start consuming CB2 record from Table A and P1 record from Table B.
   Since values in Column2 in both tables are the same, no drama here - the column3 value of the resultant table is 10.
3. Now consume the record 2 (CB1) from table A and P2 record from Table
   B. Since you could only consume 15 out from Table B from record P2
   the resultant record here is CB1,P2,15. CB1 is now left with 5
   [20-15].
4. Now the remaining 5 from CB1 is matched with the next record in
   table B which is P3. So the 3rd record in the resultant table is
   CB1,P3,5.
5. Moving on to the next new record from Table A - CB3. Since there is
   a 10 left out of the previous P3 entry from the other table the
   resultant record is CB3,P3,10. The remaining 20 of CB3 is matched by
   P4 and P5 of 10 each.

Essentially we are trying to consume the numbers from both tables and bring out the resultant tables. In the process if the numbers are leftover by the current record they are carried over to the next record.

Hopefully I haven't laid it over in a confusing manner.

The solution needs to be in the form of a SQL since it needs to go into a SQL script as I said earlier. Any guidance on how I could achieve the result is much appreciated. I am not getting an idea of how I could do this at this point in time?

Comment: How do you sort the records? you should take into consideration that records in a relational database table are unsorted by nature, meaning that without a column to use in the order by clause of the select, there is no guarantee that sql server will return the data sorted the same way each time you run the query.

Comment: Agreed. Lets say there is a key column in each of the input tables based on which the tables are sorted and the columns that we see are just a subset of columns.

Comment: Ok. what database are you working with? is it mysql, sql server or teradata?

Comment: What's the actual number of rows in both tables? Is there a way to do something like a `GROUP BY` on the data?

Comment: This problem seems almost identical to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094828/sql-server-cte-with-2-tables-until-qty-consumed/33110862#33110862) one.

Comment: I would have to implement using Teradata.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GiorgosBetsos . It looks like something very close to what I am looking for. I'll have a look.